# Page double load

Tags: javascript, html

This javascript code makes my page to double load. I haven't found the problem in it. And I have used this script before and it worked perfectly.

```
var currenttime = '<?php print date("d F Y H:i:s", time())?>' //PHP method of getting server date

var montharray=new Array("ian","feb","mar","apr","mai","iun","iul","aug","sep","oct","noi","dec")
var serverdate=new Date(currenttime)

function padlength(what){
var output=(what.toString().length==1)? "0"+what : what
return output
}

function displaytime(){
serverdate.setSeconds(serverdate.getSeconds()+1)
var datestring=padlength(serverdate.getDate())+" "+montharray[serverdate.getMonth()]+" "+serverdate.getFullYear()
var timestring=padlength(serverdate.getHours())+":"+padlength(serverdate.getMinutes())
document.getElementById("livedate").innerHTML=datestring
document.getElementById("livetime").innerHTML=timestring
setTimeout("displaytime()",  1000);
}

window.onload=displaytime;
```

This is where the time is shown:

```
<td width="180px" rowspan="6" valign="top"><div style="padding-top: 57px; padding-left: 55px;"><span class="shadow" style="font-size:14pt;color:#000000"><span id="livetime"></span></span></div>
<div style="padding-top: 15px; padding-left: 15px;"><span class="shadow" style="font-size:12pt;color:#000000"><span id="livedate"></span></span></td>
```

Perhaps you can help me. Thank you.

---

**Update:** The problem isn't with the script, is with my computer. While I was browsing I saw other sites like mine. And it's not from the browser.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a lot of semicolons...

Comment: are you sure this is the culprit code? I see nothing in here that modifies the URL, refreshes the page, etc.

Comment: On my computer with any browser I use the page is doubled. If I remove this script from the page, it looks ok. On other computers I see it is ok with the script too. It wouldn't be a problem if this was only on my computer, but I am afraid that other visitors might experience the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have recursive call of `displaytime()`. Remove it and it should work.

`displaytime() -> delay(1 sec) -> displaytime() -> delay(1 sec) -> ...`

Comment: that appears to just be updating a timestamp somewhere on the page.  Also, it's not technically recursive, because it is calling setTimeout() which returns immediately, as opposed to a recursive function which calls itself and waits for a response before returning itself.

Comment: @Matt: "Recursion" means repeating of the same pattern. Execution of the same code fragment, repeating the same figure in graphics, etc. are all recursions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion 
Here we see recursion too - the same function body executed again and again. Separated by time delays but still.

Comment: @c-smile, that is a general application of the word recursion in language.  Per your own wikipedia reference, "The most common application of recursion is in mathematics and computer science, in which it refers to a method of defining functions in which the function being defined is applied within its own definition." That is not the case here.  The work is deferred to setTimeout.  This is an important subtlety because in this case there is no base-case and no possibility of stack overflow.

Comment: Also, read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science) (results in dead link, as SO chops off trailing parenthesis - add it and it's a good link, not sure how to fix it from the comment markup)

Comment: @Matt: "the function being defined is applied within its own definition" is exactly the case here, consider this:

`function displaytime(){
   setTimeout(function() {displaytime()},  1000);
}`

Comment: @Matt: technically `setTimeout()` should store current call frame until function invocation. That means we will see typical recursive pattern here - growing list of call frames. Not on the stack but in heap.

Comment: @c-smile The keyword in that phrase is "applied".  It is not, in fact, being applied there.  It is deferred to a setTimeout call.  The function returns immediately after setTimeout call, before 'displayTime' is ever executed, and therefore never 'applied'.

Comment: @c-smile It does not, in fact, grow the call frame.  We know this by the simple fact that the call to setTimeout returns immediately.

Comment: @c-smile I believe we are trying to argue 2 different points.  From one perspective, it could be argued this is a recursive pattern, in a sense of repetition.  It is not, however, a recursive function.

Comment: @Matt: Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/5Ppzv/ - this code demonstrates typical recursion pattern - without break there it will cause crash at some point. Timer callback has access to the call frame of outer function and on each iteration here new instance of anonymous function is created.

Comment: I think we are going to have to agree to disagree on this one, c-smile :)